# Using filters with elasticsearch and tire to mimic named scopes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have an `Exhibition` model that has three named scopes:

```
scope :opening, -> { where(start_date: (Date.today .... }
scope :closing, -> { where(end_date: .... }
scope :reception, -> { where("reception is not null")... }
```

I have the following tire mapping inside the same model:

```
tire.mapping do
    ...
    indexes :start_date, type: "date"
    indexes :end_date, type: "date"
    indexes :reception, type: "date"
    ...
end
```

And my search method:

```
def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
    query { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
    ...
end
```

Inside my `exhibitions_controller.rb` I have the following (and the same for closing and reception)

```
def opening_this_week
    @exhibitions = Exhibition.opening.search(params)
    ...
end
```

When I actually search for one of the indexed fields I get back the correct response of just the exhibitions that meet the query and are opening this week, however, when I want all opening exhibitions and do not pass a search query I get ALL exhibitions, not just those that are opening this week.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I transition from a named scope to a facet? Or should I be doing it as a filter?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry @AmarH-V I didn't. I actually left the project very shortly after posting this question.